# Processing an Ajax response that returns a JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX which updates itself with an interval and returns data from a SELECT PHP.  It returns an array with multiple elements, but I don't know how to access the individual elements.  I want to use this, because I need to show the refreshed items and other different values on my web page.

The AJAX code:

```
var a=0;
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/Seyroku/extras/mostrarBote.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        data: {"a": "a"},
        success: function (respJSON) {
            //I usually use this to access the properties of the object but doesn't work
            var ItemName = respJSON.itemName;
            console.log(ItemName);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

The `mostrarBote.php` code:

```
$sql="SELECT  itemName, itemPrice, itemUrl, nameUser, color FROM potitems";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$num=1;
if ($result!=NULL) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resposta = '{"itemName":"'.$row['itemName'].'","itemPrice":"'.$row['itemPrice'].'","itemUrl":"'.$row['itemUrl'].'"}';

            if (isset($_GET['callback'])) {
                echo $_GET['callback'].'('. $resposta.')';
            } else {
                echo ($resposta); 
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

AJAX returns this response (from on console output):

> jQuery21404145154874458823_1465128123711({"itemName":"Sticker | wayLander | MLG Columbus 2016","itemPrice"
>       :"0.33","itemUrl":"http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtW
>       wKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQ0DFSua4xJ2DAgs7Ng1Qia2kMgth3ffNY3MXtd3uwteJlvKjN-KHxDsGvMYl2byYrNrxjQ3n80Q-Nzz2JIaWIQ5rfxiOrWILvkNz"
>       })jQuery21404145154874458823_1465128123711({"itemName":"Shadow Case","itemPrice":"0.03","itemUrl":"http
>       ://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo
>       4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FF4u1qubIW4Su4mzxYHbzqGtZ-KGlz8EuJcg3rnE9NiijVe3_UY-Zzr2JJjVLFEEeiQRtg"
>       })jQuery21404145154874458823_1465128123711({"itemName":"Revolver Case","itemPrice":"0.03","itemUrl":"http
>       ://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo
>       4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFYwnfKfcG9HvN7iktaOkqD1auLTxD5SvZYgiLvFpo7xjVLh-kdrYWnzcoGLMlhpsyM-5vg"
>       })jQuery21404145154874458823_1465128123711({"itemName":"Five-SeveN | Forest Night (Well-Worn)","itemPrice"
>       :"0.03","itemUrl":"http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtW
>       wKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposLOzLhRlxfbGTjVb09q5hoWYg8j6OrzZglRc7cF4n-SP9o2gjQbhqRVla2GnJ46VIQA_ZlyD-VHvxuu808S7tc7NzXFm7iUh4mGdwULQPtyarQ"
>       })

How can I access the properties ItemName, ItemPrice, and ItemUrl from the JSON elements?

Comment: Since you are getting back an array, try `respJSON[0].itemName`

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax call is configured to use 'jsonp', instead of 'json', which will not give you the results that you want / expect.  You should change the `dataType` option to 'json', and then remove the `jsonp` option (it will be ignored, anyway).

You should be able to use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to process each element of the JSON array in your Ajax `success` callback.  This will allow you to access `ItemName`, `ItemPrice`, and `ItemUrl`, as you expect.

Here is the updated Ajax code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/Seyroku/extras/mostrarBote.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        data: {"a": "a"},
        success: function (respJSON) {
            $.each(respJSON, function(index, item) {
                var itemName = item.itemName;
                var itemPrice = item.itemPrice;
                var itemUrl = item.itemUrl;
                console.log("JSON array[", index, "]: ItemName=", itemName, " ItemPrice=", itemPrice, " ItemUrl=", itemUrl);
                //TODO: Do something useful with itemName, itemPrice, and itemUrl here
            });
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```